# Visual Studio Code doesn't show Flutter errors stack trace

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code as editor for a Flutter application. The problem is that when I receive a red page of error in browser I can't see any other information about it. What I need is to show error stack trace. Same in debug console window.

I installed also VSCode extensions Dart and Flutter.

There is something to configure to resolve this problem?